# ora1031 on create table inside execute immediate

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I have procedure for creation objects krn_ddl_mgr, so creatin looks like this:

```
begin
  krn_ddl_mgr.create_object('create table krn_modules
   ( 
        id            varchar2(30 byte),
        description   varchar2(4000 byte)
   )
   tablespace MDLDATA
   rowdependencies');
end;
/
```

and it throws ora1031 insufficient privileges exception. There is only execute immediate operation in that procedure

```
procedure create_object(p_sql in clob) is
  begin
    execute immediate p_sql;
    dbms_output.put_line('create_object done');
  exception
    when others then
      case
        when (lower(p_sql) like ('create%')) and sqlcode = -955 or sqlcode = -2264 then
          null;
        when lower(p_sql) like ('alter% primary %') and sqlcode = -2260 or sqlcode = -2261 then
          null;
        when lower(p_sql) like ('alter% check %') and sqlcode = -2264 then
          null;
        when lower(p_sql) like ('alter% references %') and sqlcode = -2275 then
          null;
        else
          raise;
      end case;
  end create_object;
```

when I don't use procedure and use just create table or create table inside execute immediate statement it works. Also create_object procedure and table that I tried to create are in one schema. Why it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the owner of the `krn_ddl_mgr` has been granted the privileges to create a table through a role.

The problem is that privileges granted through a role are not active inside PL/SQL. You need to grant the necessary privileges **directly** to the owner of the package, not through a role.